# Multiple target controls for ASP.net AJAX animation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to apply the same animation to multiple TargetControlID's -- for example, in a modal dialog, I would like to have a cancel button *and* a little "x" graphic in the upper right, either of which closes the dialog.

Seems pretty inelegant to write two identical animations, one for each of these targets. I'd like to have one <AnimationExtender> and apply it to two controls.

Know what I mean? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use UpdateProgress control. It can be connected to an UpdatePanel for whatever buttons you have there.

(Or maybe I misunderstand you)

Answer (score 0):

The animation extender adds (VIA JavaScript) a click handler to the target control to start the animation.  One simple way to do what you're trying to do would be by simulating a click on the target control whenever your second control is clicked.  The AjaxControlToolkit includes a function that can help you do this.

Add this javascript to your page. Set 'onclick' of your second control to call this function:

```
function secondControlClick() {
    $common.tryFireEvent(yourtargetcontrol, 'click');
}
```

Let me know how this works out for you.

Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

... Two years later...

So the trick is in changing the TargetControlId property of the animation as you guessed. While it's not as easy as jQuery's `$["#MyControl"].hover(function {});` syntax it can be done.

There's a couple of hidden properties on the javascript objects that you need to use. The _onHoverOver, _animation, and _target properties, specifically.

For example let's say that you have a button that you'd like to resize if somebody hovers over it, you'd need to create your animation extender and a couple of javascript calls that you reference in your onmouseover event:

```
  <ajaxToolkit:AnimationExtender id="aeAnimateClaimButtons"
    runat="server" BehaviorID="showHover" TargetControlID="ctlNonExistent" >
    <Animations>
      <OnHoverOver>
        <Sequence Duration=".4">
          <Resize Width="500" Height="100" Unit="px" />
        </Sequence>
      </OnHoverOver>
      <OnHoverOut>
        <Sequence Duration=".4">
          <Resize Width="200" Height="100" Unit="px" />
        </Sequence>
      </OnHoverOut>
    </Animations>
  </ajaxToolkit:AnimationExtender>
```

Then you'd need  to create your functions:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function hoverOverButton(senderId) {
      var ae = $find("aeAnimateClaimButtons");
      ae._onHoverOver._animation._target = $get(senderId);
      ae._onHoverOver.play();
    }

    function hoverOutButton(senderId) {
      var ae = $find("aeAnimateClaimButtons");
      ae._onHoverOut._animation._target = $get(senderId);
      ae._onHoverOut.play();
    }
  </script>
```

Then your button:

```
<input type="button" onmouseover="hoverOverButton(this)" onmouseout="hoverOutButton(this)" />
```

A word of caution here. The ctlNonExistent thing will probably make your page throw an exception. This is just an example to demonstrate the principle. Also I don't know if the _variables will end up disappearing. They don't seem like public API stuff to me.